# If the colSums of a column is less than 20 the create a new column with the sum of all those columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I am interested in deleting some columns between the columns 90 and 177 with the condition that: if the colSums of the column is <20 then I delete the column.
Moreover, I want a new column which is the sum of the columns that their colSums is <20.

```
rowSums(new[,colSums(new[,90:177])<20])
```

Also, columns from 90 to 177 are related to columns from 2 to 89. If I need to delate column 90, then I also need to delete column 2, if I need to delete column 91 then I also need to delete column 3 and so on. However, I need a new column that is the sum of all the columns from 2 to 89 that needs to be deleted.

An example:

[image]

In this case: because the colsum of 90 and 92 is less than 20 I need to delete col 2, col 4 and col90 and col 92.
And create two new columns, one with the sum of col 2 and col 4. Another with the sum of col90 and col 92:

[image]

Comment: That's super hard to understand without an example input and example output

Comment: I've just add an example, thanks :)

Comment: Please read the question another time. For example "However, i need a new column that is the sum of all the columns from 2 to 89 that needs to be delated.". Why would you want to make a new column and delate (delete?) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
#Find indices of columns which have colSums less than 20
inds <- which(colSums(new[, 90:177], na.rm = TRUE) < 20)

#Add 2 new columns with rowSums from to be deleted column
df$z1 <- rowSums(new[, inds + 1])
df$z2 <- rowSums(new[, inds + 89])

#Delete paired columns
df[-c(inds + 1, inds + 89)]
```